# How Can I Load Test A Site That Uses ValidateAntiForgeryToken?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, csrf, load-testing

I would like to perform a load test on a site that uses `ValidateAntiForgeryToken`s on a number of `HttpPost`s.  However, as you would expect, when I run my load test script, I receive a number of 500 errors because the `__RequestVerificationToken` is either copied from an earlier request or is blank.  Both of which fail.

Are there any ways to load test sites where I am using the `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute on my `HttpPost` methods?

I've tried using StresStimulus and also SmartBear's LoadComplete for my tests.

Comment: comment out the validateantiforgery, all that does is get cookie value and checks to make sure its given by that form on that same URL i dont see why you would have to test stress ValidateAntiForgeryToken  however should you need to then do a cookie retrieve motion so to speak without a real cookie.  plus its worth noting that your asking "  how do i crack ValidateAntiForgeryToken "   and your title should reflect this :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using fiddler and http://stresstimulus.stimulustechnology.com/ (which I haven't used) I have to imagine you can first login, and then use that session as your load. The AntiForgeryTokens are NOT one time, and as long as the cookie is there for your auth info and an anti forgery token generated during that login session, it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with StressStimulus. Some of the forms submitted to the site were failing because the __RequestVerificationToken are not updated when the recorded request is run. {{Auto-Correlation}} did not work in my case. I used regex extractor to solve it. Here's the [link](http://community.stresstimulus.com/forum/topics/can-i-use-stresstimulus-with-a-site-that-uses-anti-forgery-tokens?commentId=6353394%3aComment:18108) to my post on StressStimulus

Comment: In the latest version of StresStimulus v4.5 auto-correlation is upgraded to support RequestVerificationToken without the need to manually create regex extrators.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the details of the scenario you are working with, it is hard to say for sure. But we've been able to automate many of these types of dynamic fields for load testing purposes (the only ones we haven't been able to bypass are those that require human input, i.e. captchas). In general, you need to find where the value of the __RequestVerificationToken field came from - be it a cookie, a javascript calculation, a hidden form field, etc. Once you've located that, you can extract or calculate that value as part of the load test scenario and send it along with the request. If my memory serves, we've tackled this one before with out much work - if you'd like to give us a shot at the problem, [contact us](http://www.webperformance.com/company/contact.html). In general, we can handle these types of problems much more gracefully than either of the solutions you mentioned.